# Translating EmrActivity to HadoopActivity in AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Imagine an AWS Data Pipeline setup that contains only the following:

- 2 EmrActivities, `myEmrActivity1` and `myEmrActivity2` that takes command-runner.jar, spark-submit and a few other arguments like Python version to use.  The arguments are different for each activity.
- 2 parameters, one for each EmrActivity

so, for example, `MyEmrActivity1` runs a spark job that calculates the total number of absences for a given year, so an example parameter for the EmrActivity for that job might be:

`myEmrActivity1: command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--master,yarn-cluster,--deploy-mode,cluster,PYTHON=python36,s3://amznhadoopactivity/school-attendance-python36/calculate_attendance_for_year.py,2017`

where 2017 indicates the year supplied to the Python script.

However, the structure of `HadoopActivity` is a bit different than it is for `EmrActivity`. `HadoopActivity` takes a Jar URI that I've filled out with `s3://dynamodb-emr-<region>/emr-ddb-storage-handler/2.1.0/emr-ddb-2.1.0.jar`, with my region inserted - let's call that `myHadoopActivity1`. However, I don't understand how exactly to link a step to an activity like I did with the Parameters - how would I recreate the behavior I set up with the EmrActivity in Data Pipeline with a HadoopActivity object instead?  Should I be using a different .jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was pretty easy to accomplish, albeit not obvious.  First things first - I *should* have been using a different .jar URI:
**/var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar**.  After changing that, the next steps were pretty straightforward.  If you were running:

```
command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--master,yarn-cluster
```

as an EMR activity, just add a HadoopActivity, put in the .jar mentioned above, then add additional arguments to replicate the behavior of the "steps" of an EmrActivity:

```
Argument: command-runner.jar
Argument: spark-submit
Argument: --master
Argument: yarn-cluster
```

so on and so forth.  So, not that difficult, but it's not also not obvious. Hope this helps someone in the future.